# Sphinx query error no field found in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thinking-sphinx

I am writing this

```
Network.search :conditions=>{:kind=>'Interest'}
```

and I am getting this error

```
 Sphinx  Sphinx Daemon returned error: index network_core: query error: no field 'kind' found in schema
```

My Code in model is

```
  define_index do
    indexes [name, description], as: :keyword
    has kind, state
  end
```

I have already run rake ts:index and rake ts:start

Comment: @MikhailNikalyukin same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your index should be looking like this:

```
define_index do
  indexes [name, description], as: :keyword
  indexes kind
  has state
end
```

After this run `bundle exec rake ts:rebuild`